# Which scores to use when use two raters?

Tags: likert, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am conducting an experiment in which two raters rate ideas for originality on a 6-point Likert scale.

I will test the raters' interrater-reliability on 10 example ideas that both raters will do beforehand. I was wondering whether it is then legit to let the two raters each rate different ideas, if the interrater-reliability is high?

Or do both raters have to rate every idea and I would use the mean for further analysis?